# Data truncated for column 'url' at row 1 - Error with programming with Python Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

The error message I got was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 416, in <module>
    startup()
  File "./test.py", line 275, in startup
    writer.save(r,data) 
  File "/home/user/project/test/output.py", line 91, in save
    self.save_doc(r, data, pid)
  File "/home/user/project/test/output.py", line 130, in save_doc
    cursor.execute(dbquery)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _warning_check
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'url' at row 1
```

The first thing I was checking is if the URL string is longer than the field length, but it is actually much shorter. 
Database Design

```
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                   |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myurlcol | CREATE DATABASE `myurlcol` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ | 
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table Design

```
  CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `host` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `content_sha1` varchar(40) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `add_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
  KEY `main_crawl_document_content_sha1` (`content_sha1`),
  KEY `main_crawl_document_discover_date` (`add_date`),
  KEY `main_crawl_document_host` (`host`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I print out the the lengths of the data I am trying to insert into the table ( I am testing using only one URL ):

```
len(url) =  89
len(md5) =  32
len(host) =  20
len(content_sha1) =  40
len(add_date) =  19
```

I was using a cursor created by Django.db.connection. To be more informative, I paste the complete database query command I passed to `cursor.execute()`

```
INSERT INTO main_document SET url='ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/0a/39/Arthritis_Res_2000_Jun_5_2%284%29_315-326.tar.gz',md5='b6ba3adde8de87e4dc255092b04d07ea',host='ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov',content_sha1='9aeab4412cc9b1add84a6d2bca574664e193b56e',add_date='2012-05-15 00:00:00';
```

The funny thing is that, the command above works when I copy and pasted to the MySQL command line. No error messages and the data are just inserted correctly.

What is going wrong?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Secator it might be a MySQL warning, but it's returning as a Python error. I guess you couldn't see that until the edit, which clears that up.

Comment: Thank you for leaving comments, but here are my questions: (1) how to remove these warnings. (2) if I have to keep them, how to ignore them and let the data be written into the database. Right now,the data is not written into the database.

Comment: I ignored the warnings using "from warnings import filterwarnings" and the data are written into the database. You know what? The Django writes a long black space after "5_2": | ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/0a/39/Arthritis_Res_2000_Jun_5_2[long space]| What's Django doing?

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute` handles MySQL escaping if you use it correctly. [Some Examples Here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

The basic idea is to use `%s` in the raw SQL string where you currently are including the raw values, and then pass a second argument to `cursor.execute()` which is a tuple (or array) of the values in order. In your case, this would look like:

```
url = 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/0a/39/Arthritis_Res_2000_Jun_5_2%284%29_315-326.tar.gz'
md5 = 'b6ba3adde8de87e4dc255092b04d07ea'
host = 'ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov'
content_sha1 = '9aeab4412cc9b1add84a6d2bca574664e193b56e'
add_date = '2012-05-15 00:00:00'
sql = "INSERT INTO main_document SET url = %s, md5 = %s, host = %s, content_sha1 = %s, add_date = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (url, md5, host, content_sha1, add_date))
```

Comment: I don't see "md5" value specified in execute statement syntax. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `urllib.unquote(url)` in order to [unquote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) the url string before inserting it into the db.  The quote character marker %, which occurs in your string, is a [special character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) for MySQL and may mangle your transaction.

Your insert should read:

```
INSERT INTO main_document SET url='ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/0a/39/Arthritis_Res_2000_Jun_5_2(4)_315-326.tar.gz',md5='b6ba3adde8de87e4dc255092b04d07ea',host='ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov',content_sha1='9aeab4412cc9b1add84a6d2bca574664e193b56e',add_date='2012-05-15 00:00:00';
```

Note that MySQL treats % only as special in pattern matching contexts.  So there may be something wrong with Django ORM here in the end.

Comment: If fanchyna is using cursor.execute() the '%'  character shouldn't be a problem, because the %s would be replaced before, isn't it?